# await bot.wait_for generates error when waiting in a command even when no one runs the command

Tags: python, discord.py

I got an error all the time whatever I write in chat (on discord) regardless of what I type, even the bots own commands generate the error and I do not understand how to solve it even when I have read through the code and the error multiple times. I think the error is after  `def check(m):` but not sure and I have tried alot of stuff trying to fix it but I do not get it to work.

This is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
```

This is the code I use:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("I am booted up and ready to run aka I am online now")
    
@bot.command()
async def play (ctx, quiz):
    channel = ctx.channel
    serverid = ctx.message.guild.id
    serverid = str(serverid)

    user = ctx.message.id
    if user == 744288177925259365:
        return
    else:

        user = str(user)

        source = "./quizzes/" + serverid
        source = "".join(source)

        source2 = source + "/" + quiz
        source2 = "".join(source2)

        if os.path.exists(source2):

            q = open(source2, "r")
            quest = q.readlines(0)
            q.close()

            print(quest[0])

            quest = "".join(quest)

            z = quest.split(" | ")

            totall = len(z)

            totall1 = totall - 1

            slow = "no"

            for y in z:
                x = y.split(", ")
                await ctx.send(x[0])

                def check(m):
                    return m.content == x[1] and m.channel == channel

                try:
                    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", timeout=10.0, check=check)

                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    slow = "yes"

                else:
                    await ctx.send("You completed the question/questions")
                return
        else:
            await ctx.send("There is no quiz with the number you entered")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire traceback? Also, do you have any `on_message` event in your code?

Comment: Mr_Spaar, I do not really get what you mean, there is nothing important in the rest of the code, it all worked but when I wrote this part of the code it all screw up and there are no on_message events in the code